# Duplicate properties/methods of an array?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am a bit confused as to why this is happening. Here is the screenshot below: [image]

As you can see, there are a few properties/methods that appear twice as I type(count, append(), underestimatedCount). This does not affect the outcome of the code, but I am wondering if this is a bug in Swift?

I was typing my array name, then `.count`:

```
shareUsers.count
```

And as I was typing the first two letters of `count`, the screenshot happened.

Comment: The screenshot is from Xcode.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I have edited my post.

Comment: @matt The OP asked if it was a bug in Swift, not Xcode. My comment was to the OP, not anyone that understands the difference between the IDE and the programming language you happen to be using.

Comment: So it *is* a bug then?

Comment: Why is my question getting close votes? I mean, it is a "why isn't this code working" question, but I think I have made my problem pretty clear, and it is very easy to reproduce it.

Comment: I don’t see any close votes. Relax! Stack Overflow is crowd sourced. People vote. You can’t find out who or why. Don’t take it personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Swift header, you'll see that `count` really is declared twice for Array — once in the "Default implementations of core requirements" extension, and once in the extension that adopts RangeReplaceableCollection. Similarly, `append(contentsOf:)` is declared twice, once the base declaration of Array, and once in the extension that adopts RangeReplaceableCollection. And so on.

I suspect that the Xcode code completion engine is simply reporting this as it sees it. It's just listing the declarations it finds in the headers.

You could reasonably file a bug report about Xcode's behavior in this regard, I think. The Swift header itself is not unreasonable but there's no good reason why the code completion engine needs to reflect the repeated declarations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is my question a valid one? Why is it getting downvotes?